# How to implement custom controller action selection in ASP.Net Core?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an ASP.Net Core API project. I want to be able to write a custom routing logic to be able to choose different controller actions based on HTTP Body parameters. To illustrate my problem, this is my `Controller` class:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class TestController
{
    // should be called when HTTP Body contains json: '{ method: "SetValue1" }'
    public void SetValue1()
    {
        // some logic
    }

    // should be called when HTTP Body contains json: '{ method: "SetValue2" }'
    public void SetValue2()
    {
        // some logic
    }
}
```

As you can see from my comments I want to choose different action methods based on HTTP body.
Here is my `Startup` class:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        // I assume instead of this built in routing middleware, 
        // I will have to implement custom middleware to choose the correct endpoints, from HTTP body,
        // any ideas how I can go about this?
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

One of the option I could use is having one entry Action method that will call differnt methods based on the HTTP Body content, but I would like to avoid that and encapsulate this logic somewhere in a custom routing.

In the old `APS.Net Web API` there was a handy class [ApiControllerActionSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/hh835196(v=vs.118)) that I could extend, and define my custom logic of selecting Action methods, however this is not supported in new `ASP.Net Core`. I think I will have to implement my own version of `app.UseRouting` middleware. Any ideas on how I can do it?

Comment: If you decide which action is executed, then it means that the caller does not care which action is executed as long the job is done, correct? If that's fine with you, I suggest a different approach - create a single action that calls a service that decides with what kind of request it deals with e.g. by reading a field with request type. If the request type is supported, create a handler for it and execute logic that handler offers. I use this technique when integrating with third-party Webhook. One endpoint for several types of events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the old `asp.net core` (before `3.0`), we can implement a custom `IActionSelector` and it's especially convenient when the `ActionSelector` is still made public. But with the new endpoint routing, it's changed to the so-called `EndpointSelector`. The implementation is fairly the same, the point is how we extract the `ActionDescriptor` which is put in the `Endpoint` as metadata. The following implementation requires a default `EndpointSelector` (which is `DefaultEndpointSelector`) but that's unfortunately made internal. So we need to use a trick to get an instance of that default implementation to use in our custom implementation.

```
public class RequestBodyEndpointSelector : EndpointSelector
{
    readonly IEnumerable<Endpoint> _controllerEndPoints;
    readonly EndpointSelector _defaultSelector;
    public RequestBodyEndpointSelector(EndpointSelector defaultSelector, EndpointDataSource endpointDataSource)
    {
        _defaultSelector = defaultSelector;
        _controllerEndPoints = endpointDataSource.Endpoints
                                                 .Where(e => e.Metadata.GetMetadata<ControllerActionDescriptor>() != null).ToList();
    }
    public override async Task SelectAsync(HttpContext httpContext, CandidateSet candidates)
    {
        var request = httpContext.Request;
        request.EnableBuffering();
        //don't use "using" here, otherwise the request.Body will be disposed and cannot be used later in the pipeline (an exception will be thrown).
        var sr = new StreamReader(request.Body);
        try
        {
            var body = sr.ReadToEnd();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(body))
            {
                try
                {
                    var actionInfo = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ActionInfo>(body);
                    var controllerActions = new HashSet<(MethodInfo method, Endpoint endpoint, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, int score)>();
                    var constrainedControllerTypes = new HashSet<Type>();
                    var routeValues = new List<RouteValueDictionary>();
                    var validIndices = new HashSet<int>();
                    for (var i = 0; i < candidates.Count; i++)
                    {
                        var candidate = candidates[i];
                        var endpoint = candidates[i].Endpoint;
                        var actionDescriptor = endpoint.Metadata.GetMetadata<ControllerActionDescriptor>();
                        if (actionDescriptor == null) continue;
                        routeValues.Add(candidate.Values);
                        constrainedControllerTypes.Add(actionDescriptor.MethodInfo.DeclaringType);
                        if (!string.Equals(actionInfo.MethodName, actionDescriptor.MethodInfo.Name,
                                           StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) continue;
                        if (!controllerActions.Add((actionDescriptor.MethodInfo, endpoint, candidate.Values, candidate.Score))) continue;
                        validIndices.Add(i);
                    }
                    if (controllerActions.Count == 0)
                    {
                        var bestCandidates = _controllerEndPoints.Where(e => string.Equals(actionInfo.MethodName,
                                                                                           e.Metadata.GetMetadata<ControllerActionDescriptor>().MethodInfo.Name,
                                                                                           StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToArray();
                        var routeValuesArray = request.RouteValues == null ? routeValues.ToArray() : new[] { request.RouteValues };
                        candidates = new CandidateSet(bestCandidates, routeValuesArray, new[] { 0 });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        for(var i = 0; i < candidates.Count; i++)
                        {
                            candidates.SetValidity(i, validIndices.Contains(i));                                
                        }                            
                    }
                    //call the default selector after narrowing down the candidates
                    await _defaultSelector.SelectAsync(httpContext, candidates);
                    //if some endpoint found
                    var selectedEndpoint = httpContext.GetEndpoint();
                    if (selectedEndpoint != null)
                    {
                        //update the action in the RouteData to found endpoint                            
                        request.RouteValues["action"] = selectedEndpoint.Metadata.GetMetadata<ControllerActionDescriptor>().ActionName;
                    }
                    return;
                }
                catch { }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            request.Body.Position = 0;
        }
        await _defaultSelector.SelectAsync(httpContext, candidates);
    }
}
```

The registration code is a bit tricky like this:

```
//define an extension method for registering conveniently
public static class EndpointSelectorServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddRequestBodyEndpointSelector(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //build a dummy service container to get an instance of 
        //the DefaultEndpointSelector
        var sc = new ServiceCollection();
        sc.AddMvc();
        var defaultEndpointSelector = sc.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<EndpointSelector>();            
        return services.Replace(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(EndpointSelector),
                                sp => new RequestBodyEndpointSelector(defaultEndpointSelector, 
                                                                      sp.GetRequiredService<EndpointDataSource>()),
                                ServiceLifetime.Singleton));
    }
}

//inside the Startup.ConfigureServices
services.AddRequestBodyEndpointSelector();
```

---

**The old solution for the old conventional routing used in asp.net core 2.2**

Your requirement is a bit weird and you may have to accept some trade-off for that. First that requirement may require you to read the `Request.Body` twice (when the selected action method has some arguments to model-bind). Even when the framework supports the so-called `EnableBuffering` on the `HttpRequest`, it's still a bit trade-off to accept. Secondly in the method to select the best action (defined on `IActionSelector`), we cannot use `async` so reading the request body of course cannot be done with `async`.

For high performance web apps, that definitely should be avoided. But if you can accept that kinds of trade-off, we have a solution here by implementing a custom `IActionSelector`, at best let it inherit from the default `ActionSelector`. The method we can override is `ActionSelector.SelectBestActions`. However that method does not provide the `RouteContext` (we need access to that to update the `RouteData`), so we'll re-implement another method of `IActionSelector` named `IActionSelector.SelectBestCandidate` which provides a `RouteContext`.

Here's the detailed code:

```
//first we define a base model for parsing the request body
public class ActionInfo
{
    [JsonProperty("method")]
    public string MethodName { get; set; }
}

//here's our custom ActionSelector
public class RequestBodyActionSelector : ActionSelector, IActionSelector
{        
    readonly IEnumerable<ActionDescriptor> _actions;
    public RequestBodyActionSelector(IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider actionDescriptorCollectionProvider, 
        ActionConstraintCache actionConstraintCache, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) 
        : base(actionDescriptorCollectionProvider, actionConstraintCache, loggerFactory)
    {            
        _actions = actionDescriptorCollectionProvider.ActionDescriptors.Items;            
    }
    ActionDescriptor IActionSelector.SelectBestCandidate(RouteContext context, IReadOnlyList<ActionDescriptor> candidates)
    {
        var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
        //supports reading the request body multiple times
        request.EnableBuffering();
        var sr = new StreamReader(request.Body);
        try
        {
            var body = sr.ReadToEnd();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(body))
            {
                try
                {
                    //here I use the old Newtonsoft.Json
                    var actionInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ActionInfo>(body);
                    //the best actions should be on these controller types.
                    var controllerTypes = new HashSet<TypeInfo>(candidates.OfType<ControllerActionDescriptor>().Select(e => e.ControllerTypeInfo));
                    //filter for the best by matching the controller types and 
                    //the method name from the request body
                    var bestActions = _actions.Where(e => e is ControllerActionDescriptor ca &&
                                                          controllerTypes.Contains(ca.ControllerTypeInfo) &&
                                                         string.Equals(actionInfo.MethodName, ca.MethodInfo.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList();
                    //only override the default if any method name matched 
                    if (bestActions.Count > 0)
                    {
                        //before reaching here, 
                        //the RouteData has already been populated with 
                        //what from the request's URL
                        //By overriding this way, that RouteData's action
                        //may be changed, so we need to update it here.
                        var newActionName = (bestActions[0] as ControllerActionDescriptor).ActionName;                            
                        context.RouteData.PushState(null, new RouteValueDictionary(new { action = newActionName }), null);

                        return SelectBestCandidate(context, bestActions);
                    }
                }
                catch { }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            request.Body.Position = 0;
        }
        return SelectBestCandidate(context, candidates);
    }        
}
```

To register the custom `IActionSelector` in the `Startup.ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddSingleton<IActionSelector, RequestBodyActionSelector>();
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out! It seems `ActionSelector` class is not available in `ASP.Net Core 5.0`. I modified your code a little bit without inheriting from `ActionSelector`. I did register `RequestBodyActionSelector` in my `Startup` class, but unfortunatelly for some reason it never gets called, the controller and actions are selected as they normally are. Is there any specific setup that I'm missing? Can you please add to your answer your `Startup` and `Controller` classes code? I would also really appreciate if it was compliant with `ASP.Net Core 5.0`

Comment: @MykhailoSeniutovych have you registered the `IActionSelector` as guided at the end of the answer? I'm not very familiar with `.net 5`, but looks like the routing is a bit different in `.net 5`, I would try adding this `app.UseRouting()` in the `Startup.Configure` as well.

Comment: @MykhailoSeniutovych I've just updated the answer with a solution using endpoint routing (actually it was partly introduced in `asp.net core 2.2` and can be enabled by setting `MvcOptions.EnableEndpointRouting = true`). That's why I could proceed to write & test it.

Comment: I tested `2.2` code and it works so I will accept the answer. Unfortunatelly the newer code with `EndpointSelector` does not work in `ASP.Net Core 3.1` and above, because you are using `EndpointSelectorContext` class there, which does not exist in those newer versions.

Comment: @MykhailoSeniutovych thanks for your response, actually I could not test it on `.net core 3.1`, I thought that design is kept unchanged since 2.2. Actually the code is almost the same, the `RouteValues` from `EndpointSelectorContext` is moved to `HttpRequest.RouteValues` and the `Endpoint` can be get/set using extension methods on `HttpContext` instead. I've just updated the code using a custom `EndpointSelector`, of course I cannot test it. Hope you can test it yourself. You should use the newer version of `asp.net core` if possible.

Comment: A simpler and cleaner way to do the service registration is to use [Scrutor](https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor) `Decorate` method, like so...

`services.Decorate<EndpointSelector, RequestBodyEndpointSelector>();`